# ZF2 - Add pages to navigation in the controller

Tags: zend-framework2

In my project I have a navigation, which is created from an array in a config.php file using the default factory. I want to add subpages to the current pages in the controller.

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function newpageAction() {
        $navigation = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('navigation');
        $currentPage = $navigation->findById('index');

        $options = array(
            'id'         => 'newpage',
            'label'      => 'New Page',
            'route'      => 'my-route',
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action'     => 'newpage',
            'active'     => true,
        );
        $newpage = new \Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc($options);

        $currentPage->addPage($newpage);
    }
}
```

The page is added successfully but then I try to create the url for the page in the breadcrumbs view using the getHref() method of the page:

```
<?php foreach($this->pages as $page) {?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $page->getHref();?>"><?php echo $page->getLabel();?></a>
</li>
<?php }?>
```

But I get the following error for the newly added pages:

```
Additional information:
Zend\Navigation\Exception\DomainException

File:
\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc.php:198

Message:

Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::getHref cannot execute as no Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStackInterface instance is composed
```

I guess the problem is in the way I create and add the pages to the navigation. Is there another way to do that or how I fix this error?

I want to add the pages after the 3th level in the controller instead of in the config file because there are params in the urls of the pages and the labels are dynamic.
Any suggestions for accomplishing this task in any other way are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the `MVC` page having unmet dependencies (the router). It is [the factory's job to inject these components](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Service/AbstractNavigationFactory.php) (depending on a URI or MVC type).

To make sure each MVC page has router injected create *a new factory* that in turn uses another already provided factory [`Zend\Navigation\Service\ConstructedNavigationFactory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Navigation/Service/ConstructedNavigationFactory.php) to create your own navigation container and return it's pages. In your example this will be just one page.

---

**EDIT**

If you *have* to add the navigation pages in the controller, where you do not know the page config prior to the `newpageAction()`; You could extend the class to allow config to be set within the controller.

For example

```
public function MyCustomNavFactory extends ConstructedNavigationFactory
{
  // make the config optional
  public function __construct($config = array())
  {
    $this->config = $config;
  }
  // Allow config to be set outside the class
  public function setConfig($config)
  {
    $this->config = $config;
  }

}
```

**Module.php**

```
// Module
public function getServiceConfig() {
  return array(
    'invokables' => array(
      // Create the factory as an invokable (as there are no __construct args)
      'MyCustomNavFactory' => 'App\Navigation\Service\MyCustomNavFactory'
    ),
  );
}
```

The controller call would then just be simply just use

```
// Controller
public function newpageAction()
{
  $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();
  $navigation = $serviceManager->get('MyCustomNavFactory');

  $options = array(
    'id'         => 'newpage',
    'label'      => 'New Page',
    'route'      => 'my-route',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'newpage',
    'active'     => true,
  );
  $navigation->setConfig($options);
  $pages = $navigation->getPages($serviceManager);
}
```

Comment: Thanks AlexP for your answer. Now I get it why the url generation does not work. But in your solution the $options of the pages are in the factory and if I want to create other custom pages I should create another factory I guess. Is there another way to provide the $options for each custom page.
I think, I can use the ConstructedNavigationFactory directly in the controller action or this is a bad design?

Comment: @ElenaSlavcheva I've updated my answer - not knowing the `$options` prior to the controller action will change the approach. I'm sure there is a 'cleaner' solution (like moving the above code in the controller to a service layer); I personally would want all the "new pages" in config somewhere and have a factory for each different "new page" which would avoid possible code duplication.

Answer (score 4):

You could add the default router.

```
\Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc::setDefaultRouter ($this->getServiceLocator ()->get ('router'));
```

Comment: Thanks akond!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150958/1908296) of [@AlexP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449814/alexp) is correct.

**But** there error into Controller Action As when he call custom factory using `ServiceLocator` will get Object of type [`AbstractContainer`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-navigation/blob/master/src/AbstractContainer.php) Object Because `ServiceLocator` will call `createService` method into your custom factory (`MyCustomNavFactory`) which extends [`AbstractNavigationFactory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-navigation/blob/master/src/Service/AbstractNavigationFactory.php) So the next line will call `setConfig` method into `AbstractContainer` Object not into your custom factory (`MyCustomNavFactory`).

The correct Way to Set Breadcrumb configuration from Controller Action is:

```
// Controller
public function newpageAction()
{
  $serviceManager    = $this->getServiceLocator();
  $navigationFactory = new MyCustomNavFactory();

  $options = array(
    'id'         => 'newpage',
    'label'      => 'New Page',
    'route'      => 'my-route',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'newpage',
    'active'     => true,
  );
  $navigationFactory->setConfig($options);
  $pages = $navigationFactory->getPages($serviceManager);
}
```

**OR**

Remove `setConfig` method form custom factory and set configuration using it's Constructor

```
// custom Factory
public function MyCustomNavFactory extends ConstructedNavigationFactory
{
  // make the config optional
  public function __construct($config = array())
  {
    parent::__construct($config);
  }
}
```

Then Controller will be:

```
// Controller
public function newpageAction()
{
  $serviceManager = $this->getServiceLocator();    
  $options = array(
     array(
       'id'         => 'newpage',
       'label'      => 'New Page',
       'route'      => 'my-route',
       'controller' => 'index',
       'action'     => 'newpage',
       'active'     => true,
    )
  );
  $navigationFactory = new MyCustomNavFactory($options);
  $pages = $navigationFactory->getPages($serviceManager);
}
```